Since different tenses
I want to use "since" meaning "after" not "because".

I haven't seen her since she works there

I haven't seen her since she is working there

I haven't seen her since she has been working there.

I haven't seen here since she was working there


The reason I'm asking is because I have seen such sentences only with past simple and past perfect simple. To me my 4 versions are also fine and mean more or less the same. Still, I'm not a native so please comment on them.

1, 2 - NO. 3, 4 - OK.

Setting aside Michael Harvey's concerns, I would say that all 4 examples are ambiguous to some extent. You can substitute the word "because" for "since" and not change the meaning if that is what you intended. On the other hand substituting "after", although a bit awkward sounding to a native speaker, also works. Something like " Since / after she started working there I have not seen her" may be better.

@MichaelHarvey   why 1 and 2 won't work?

@MichaelHarvey  what if I accept "since" to mean "because"? Are then all 4 examples correct?

All four are both unnatural and ambiguous. If you mean 'because', you should use that word.

If your main goal is to learn how tenses work in English, I’d suggest you say so. If, instead, your goal is to express a particular thought in idiomatic English, then you can avoid all the tense issues that your examples are raising for you. How about I haven’t seen her since she started working there?

Your 1 and 2 don’t work because sentences of the form I haven’t done X since Y, where since is used in its temporal sense rather than its conjunctive sense, carry the implicit semantic requirement that Y have already happened.

(1) and (2) are not idiomatic English, and, no, I can't tell you why - just 'because'. (3) is idiomatic if she is working there now. (4) is OK if she no longer is - it would imply since she stopped working there. (I see Paul has supplied a reason!)

@PaulTanenbaum what iif we mean since=because  1 I haven't she her since/because she is working there. It's correct then?

Depends on context, on exactly what you mean. Is it that her working there has caused you to choose not to see her? Or maybe that her working there somehow prevents her from being seen by you? Or some third meaning?

Prevents I'm not able to see her because of that

I'm not feeling terribly confident, since several commenters have defended it, but I'm not sure that #3 works either. I'm going to tentatively say that "since," in the meaning you want, is about the past, so only past tenses work.
Something similar to #3 is "I haven't seen her since she has started working there." To my mind, that works, since it speaks of a discrete moment in the past. It implies that her work is ongoing in the present, but the start of her work is a past moment. Of course, I don't know why anyone would say this, instead of "...since she started working there."
In short: You say "I have seen such sentences only with past simple and past perfect simple." I think there's a good reason for that. Note, this isn't so much about grammar as about ideas. Don't get the idea that "there's a rule that 'since' takes certain tenses." Rather, it's: "This meaning of 'since' is about discrete moments in the past. So it's hard to use it with verb tenses that don't handle that idea."
